Transitioning from setuptools to Poetry: Issues with Scripts and Package Data
I'm migrating a Python project from setuptools to Poetry and encountering issues with my scripts not being recognized and including non-code files. Below is how I previously configured my project using setuptools in setup.py:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = "1.0.0"

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'my_package.merge': ['*.sh']
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    url='repo_url',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_amazin_func=my_package.fun:entrypoint'
        ]
    }
)


Now, I'm trying to achieve the same functionality using poetry. Here's my current pyproject.toml configuration:
[tool.poetry]
name = "my package"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My Amazing package"
authors = ["AAA"]
readme = "README.md"
include = [
    'my_package/merge/*.sh'
]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_amazin_func = "my_package.fun:entrypoint"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10.1,<3.11"

[tool.flake8]
max-line-length = 100
select = ['E9', 'F63', 'F7', 'F82']
count = true
show-source = true
statistics = true
max-complexity = 10

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
nose = "1.3.7"
pytest = "8.1.1"
pytest-mock = "3.14.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Issue
The function my_amazin_func is intended to be used like a CLI tool, but it is not recognized after migration. How can I ensure that my_amazin_func is correctly recognized as a command line script, and how can I include specific non-code files as I did with package_data in setuptools?
Additional Notes
I have ensured that poetry install was run after updating pyproject.toml.
I have checked the virtual environment to confirm that the script is not present.
Any guidance on how to properly configure Poetry to replace the functionality previously handled by setuptools would be greatly appreciated.

I do not see any issue in pyproject.toml shown in the question. This seems like it should work. -- Have you tried building the wheel, installing that wheel in a separate virtual environment, and checking the CLI entry point in that virtual environment?

it acutally works as @sinoroc mentioned the issue was in installing the package using poetry
